# "Data is missing" error occasionally appears

Tags: 2sxc

DNN 7.4.2
2SXC 8.8.0

I upgraded to 8.8.0 from 5.5.0. The upgrade went successfully. I only had 2 content types and templates. Now I've added many new content types and templates (more than a dozen) and I've started adding them to my pages.

I'm running into a problem where, every once in awhile, when I browse to a page with Content dropped on the page, I see a module error message that says "Data is missing - usually when a site is copied but the content / apps have not been imported yet..." The error appears for each Content module on the page.

The strange thing is that I never actually exported/imported - I created all my content types and templates from scratch. The problem is also intermittent - sometimes I see the problem, other times it looks normal.

I know our site has some caching on it. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Yes, caching could have that effect - more specifically if you have multiple IIS threads of a farm, where one server doesn't know about the other server refreshing the cache. Does this apply to your scenario? Could you give more details about the caching and what actions you perform, to "resolve" the situation (how does it fix itself)?

Comment: I'll find out about the multiple IIS threads of a farm. I'm not sure yet. For resolving, it just resolves itself after I browse away from the page.

Comment: Does F5 solve it as well? Or Ctrl+F5? or F5 with debug (F12) open?

Comment: Everything seems okay now. It's hosted on Azure and the IT guy told me they were doing maintenance on it around the same time which caused some problems. I think it did have to do with caching to some degree. If I find out the exact reason, I'll let you know later. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ok, in this case we'll presume this is closed